# Can I read/update only a part of an entity using entity core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-security

I have the User entity that contains the Email/Name/.../HashedPassword/Salt.

Now, every time, after the user logs in the entire User entity goes to the client so that the user can modify some of the properties.

However I would prefer not to send the last two properties; but if I set them to null before send them to client, then when the entity comes back, I would need to get the original entity from the database, set the two properties to the just arrived entity then save it.

Is there a better solution, like saving only a part of the entity?
Or maybe I am security paranoid and this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For avoiding reading, you can just select a new object without the properties you do not want to expose:

```
   return user.Select(x => new User
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Email = x.Email,
            Name = x.Name,
        });
```

Your update procedure is the correct way to handle this.